# Bluetooth low energy iOS how get service name

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have one Bluetooth device with some service. I'm able to connect my app with this device, and I'm able to see all services of my BT device, but I would like to see what is the name of the various services, for example:

```
Device Information 
UUID : 0x180A
```

I think it is possible because some universal app allow you to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Apple tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1), it is very clear there :

Starting with:

```
@interface ViewController () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>

//centralManager:willRestoreState:
@property (nonatomic,strong) CBPeripheral     *connectingPeripheral;

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    CBCentralManager *centralManager;
}
```

Then:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Starting Up a Central Manager
    centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil
                                                    options: nil]; 
}
```

initWithDelegate: queue: options: calls through CBCentralManagerDelegate:

```
- (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil //Services
                                           options:nil];
}
```

scanForPeripheralsWithServices: options: calls through CBCentralManagerDelegate:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral;

    //You should connect to your BLE Device with:
    [centralManager connectPeripheral:self.connectingPeripheral
                              options: nil]
}
```

The response of this call is through the delegate connectPeripheral: options:

Then:

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    //(...)
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil]; // Service
}
```

discoverServices: calls peripheral: didDiscoverServices: from CBPeripheralDelegate

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services)
    {
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@", service);
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@", service.UUID);
    }
}
```

There you have what you want!

It is important to know the properties of a [CBService](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBService_Class/translated_content/CBService.html):

Identifying a Service

- UUID  property
- peripheral  property
- isPrimary  property

Accessing Service Data

- characteristics  property
- includedServices  property